# Strange output from pivot_wider. Tibble produced is different from the View(df) output. (includes dput and code!)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to turn the following dataset into a wider format where the species names in Full_name become column headers and the values from counts500 go into each of those columns. The ID column should have no repeats.

| Year | Location | Site | Depth | Transect | ID | Full_name | counts500 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Tela | AD | 10 | 1 | 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 | Stegastes planifrons | 0 |
| 2019 | Tela | AD | 10 | 1 | 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 | Anisotremus virginicus | 1 |
| 2019 | Tela | AD | 10 | 1 | 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 | Stegastes adustus | 0 |
| 2019 | Tela | AD | 10 | 1 | 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 | Stegastes partitus | 0 |
| 2019 | Tela | AD | 10 | 1 | 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 | Stegastes partitus | 0 |
| 2019 | Tela | AD | 10 | 1 | 2019_Tela_AD_1_10 | Stegastes partitus | 0 |

The code I used was:

```
> dfnew <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = Full_name, values_from = counts500, values_fn = list) ###Pivoting dataset wider to give species as columns
```

This returns a dataset that looks correct (in View(df)) but gives a tibble when I just type 'df' into the console which has incorrect values. Could it be that it's counting the occurrences of each species per ID rather than taking the values from counts500 column?

Here is the dput of a my top table with more rows:

```r
structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Location = c("Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela"), Site = c("AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD"), Depth = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), Transect = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ID = c("2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10"
), Full_name = c("Stegastes planifrons", "Anisotremus virginicus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes variabilis", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Serranus tortugarum", "Serranus tortugarum", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Microspathodon chrysurus", "Abudefduf saxatilis", "Microspathodon chrysurus", 
"Haemulon carbonarium", "Microspathodon chrysurus", "Abudefduf saxatilis", 
"Acanthurus coeruleus", "Haemulon chrysargyreum", "Anisotremus virginicus", 
"Anisotremus virginicus", "Sparisoma viride", "Caranx ruber", 
"Scarus vetula", "Halichoeres bivittatus", "Scarus iseri", "Sparisoma viride", 
"Anisotremus virginicus", "Sparisoma viride", "Scarus iseri", 
"Scarus iseri", "Scarus iseri", "Scarus vetula", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Scarus iseri", "Microspathodon chrysurus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Microspathodon chrysurus", "Microspathodon chrysurus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", "Scarus iseri", "Stegastes diencaeus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Haemulon sciurus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Anisotremus virginicus", "Lutjanus mahogoni", 
"Scarus vetula", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Holacanthus tricolor", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes partitus", "Halichoeres maculipinna", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes variabilis", "Microspathodon chrysurus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes variabilis", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes diencaeus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Thalassoma bifasciatum", "Chaetodon capistratus", "Haemulon carbonarium", 
"Haemulon carbonarium", "Stegastes adustus", "Thalassoma bifasciatum", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes partitus"), counts500 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")))
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks like your dput output might be missing something

Comment: Two closing braces are missing at the end

Comment: `pivot_wider()` always returns a tibble. Since you have list columns, only type and length of the can be seen in the printed tibble in the console. The viewer shows the contained vectors up to a certain length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, where there are multiple rows which are all the same, you wish to add together the counts, and where there are none of the species observed you want a zero. That being the case, you can do:

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(exfibi500, names_from = Full_name, values_from = counts500, 
              values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 29
#>    Year Location Site  Depth Transect ID       `Stegastes pla~` `Anisotremus v~`
#>   <int> <chr>    <chr> <int>    <int> <chr>               <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1  2019 Tela     AD       10        1 2019_Te~                0                4
#> 2  2019 Tela     AD       10        2 2019_Te~                0                0
#> 3  2019 Tela     AD       10        3 2019_Te~                0                0
#> # ... with 21 more variables: `Stegastes adustus` <dbl>,
#> #   `Stegastes partitus` <dbl>, `Stegastes variabilis` <dbl>,
#> #   `Serranus tortugarum` <dbl>, `Microspathodon chrysurus` <dbl>,
#> #   `Abudefduf saxatilis` <dbl>, `Haemulon carbonarium` <dbl>,
#> #   `Acanthurus coeruleus` <dbl>, `Haemulon chrysargyreum` <dbl>,
#> #   `Sparisoma viride` <dbl>, `Caranx ruber` <dbl>, `Scarus vetula` <dbl>,
#> #   `Halichoeres bivittatus` <dbl>, `Scarus iseri` <dbl>, ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Actually I dont, they're correct as they are. I just need to pivot them without having the above issue of difference between my tibble and my View(df)

Comment: @Bill_marinestats98 but you have multiple rows with all the same values apart from counts, so the result you see in `View` is that each species has a list column, with some entries being NULL for some species. If that's what you want, I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: In `View`, you are seeing that some of the cells in the various species column contain a whole vector. That's why I assumed you wanted to add them. The species columns aren't really columns at all, but lists. They look OK in `View`, and you can manipulate them if you want, but how you want to handle them isn't discussed in your question.

Comment: So what I'm going to unnest the tibble once the values are correct to give me a column of the counts500. Which I am then going to add to another dataset I've made. I've already counted up the duplicate rows using ave() etc. When I try to unnest the tibble I'm left with the wrong values. E.g. When I View() the df I get c(1, 1, 1, 1) which is fine as I can just use some code to unnest, but I currently just have the wrong values in my tibble when I use my code. It doesn't seem to be using the 'counts500' as the source of values for my pivoted table. Sorry I'm struggling to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `distinct` and then `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(distinct(df), names_from = Full_name, values_from = counts500)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 29
   Year Location Site  Depth Transect ID                `Stegastes plan… `Anisotremus vi… `Stegastes adus… `Stegastes part… `Stegastes vari… `Serranus tortu…
  <int> <chr>    <chr> <int>    <int> <chr>                        <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1  2019 Tela     AD       10        1 2019_Tela_AD_1_10                0                1                0                0                0                0
2  2019 Tela     AD       10        2 2019_Tela_AD_2_10               NA                0                0                0               NA               NA
3  2019 Tela     AD       10        3 2019_Tela_AD_3_10               NA               NA                0                0                0               NA
# … with 17 more variables: Microspathodon chrysurus <dbl>, Abudefduf saxatilis <dbl>, Haemulon carbonarium <dbl>, Acanthurus coeruleus <dbl>,
#   Haemulon chrysargyreum <dbl>, Sparisoma viride <dbl>, Caranx ruber <dbl>, Scarus vetula <dbl>, Halichoeres bivittatus <dbl>, Scarus iseri <dbl>,
#   Stegastes diencaeus <dbl>, Haemulon sciurus <dbl>, Lutjanus mahogoni <dbl>, Holacanthus tricolor <dbl>, Halichoeres maculipinna <dbl>,
#   Thalassoma bifasciatum <dbl>, Chaetodon capistratus <dbl>
```

Comment: Does this drop some of the observations @akrun?

Comment: @AllanCameron `distinct` is done on the whole data.  So I am not clear about your question

Comment: This looks ideal. Then will the NAs cause me any issues when I try to unnest it? Are the NAs masking any values that aren't zero?

Comment: @Bill_marinestats98 that you can change it to 0 with `values_fill = 0` as in the AllanCameron's solution